# Size of package Zend Framework installed through Composer

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php

I was just wondering why the package "zendframework/zendframework1" on Composer was so big:

```
[root@server-VM-001:vendor #] du -sh zendframework/
558M    zendframework/
```

Can someone explain?

By the way, is it possible to get the Zend Framework minimal package through Composer?

Answer (score 0):

If you install dev-master or another dev- version, composer by default installs it "from source" which means it does a git clone. Given ZF is large and has a long history, the complete repository is quite huge.

The solution for now is to just install tagged releases which are downloaded as dist (zip archives in composer lingo). In the not-so-distant future there should also be a `--prefer-dist` flag you can pass to composer install that will force dists even for dev packages.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it when you say "The solution for now is to just install tagged releases which are downloaded as dist". Do you mean not using Composer to install the minimal package?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that if you require 2.0.0 it will install as a small-ish zip, if you require dev-master it will clone the 500MB blob.

Comment: If you try to grab the 1.12.0, you will get the 558M file. Here's what's in my composer.json (within the 'require' section): `"zendframework/zendframework1": "1.12.0"`

Comment: Oh sorry that's ZF1 which is svn. There I guess it can't be helped.

Comment: Is there a possiblity to exclude certain folders for the install, e.g. tests, externals, documentation, demos? This would greatly reduce the packet size...